# Location for passing flask-socket events to the uWSGI server via nginx proxy in Docker

Tags: docker, nginx, socket.io, uwsgi, flask-socketio

I am trying to use Socket-IO events (based on Flask-SocketIO) with my uwsgi and nginx setup on Docker. I am not sure how I should configure my nginx file to allow for the socket connection between client and server. Here is my current nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;

    location / {
        try_files $uri @app;
    }

    location @app {
        include /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass myapp:8080;
    }

    location /socket.io {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        uwsgi_pass myapp:8080/socket.io;
    }
}
```

Docker Compose:

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  web_server:
    container_name: nginx
    external_links:
      - app
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: server/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - app
  app:
    container_name: myapp
  build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: application/Dockerfile
    expose:
      - 8080
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Flask-SocketIO documentation shows an example nginx configuration. Here the Socket.IO location block from it:

```
    location /socket.io {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/socket.io;
    }
```

The entire configuration is [here](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#using-nginx-as-a-websocket-reverse-proxy).

You are using uwsgi_pass, which based on my understanding does not support proxying WebSocket connections. Use HTTP as this example shows.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - what is proxy params in this case? I get an error when trying to use it. A file I need to define?

Comment: It is a file with standard definitions. Some distributions of nginx include it, but I guess not all do if you don't have it. Here is a copy of it: https://github.com/Mechazawa/nginx-config/blob/master/nginx/proxy_params.

Comment: I have made the step to HTTP based server, however it still does not work. Any other ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You're going to need to debug this and provide additional information. I've seen tons of applications deployed with nginx as shown above, some I maintain myself. So I know this solution works. Can you connect directly to the uWSGI server from your browser, for example?

Comment: How would this be possible - without using nginx at all? I can run it over the localhost by executing the script directly, it connects to the database and allows me to use the sockets just fine, but this would not be with uwsgi.

Comment: If you run uwsgi in http mode it works exactly in the same way as the development server. You can connect to it from the browser.

Comment: Okay, I think we are getting closer (thanks for keeping the replies up btw) - if I run the server with 'uwsgi --http-socket :8080 --wsgi-file uwsgi.py', then I am getting an error that I do not get, when I am running it over 'flask run': "ImportError: dlopen: Symbol not found: _PyExc_MemoryError". Any idea why this bug would appear when using uwsgi? Does it have anything to do with the sockets?

Comment: Never seen this error before, so I don't know. But it seems you haven't looked at the documentation. If you run uWSGI you also have to use gevent, uWSGI on its own is not a supported configuration for Flask-SocketIO.

Comment: What I found recently, is that the socket does work occasionally when running it on my docker setup i.e. every third message will actually be passed to through the proxy correctly. Is there any reason why only some messages might go through?

Comment: I switched to gunicorn for the proxy also and combined it with eventlet.